# Securing NestJS API for Angular App with Auth0

Tags: angular, nestjs, auth0

I'm working on an Angular app that uses NestJS as the backend. We have authentication working in the Angular app, logging in to Auth0 and redirecting back to our app. I can see the `/token` call in the network tab, and see the response. It all works great.

My issue is with the NestJS app, and with getting data from it when the guard is added to a route. I followed [this guide directly from the Auth0 site](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-a-secure-api-with-nestjs-adding-authorization), but I'm still having issues. I have the auth module, the `jwt.strategy.ts` service, and everything. However, I can't hit the protected route.

On Auth0's site, I've created an Application for the Angular app, and an API for the NestJS app. I am taking the token from the Angular app and plugging it in to Insomnia to make a call to a route, `http://localhost:3333/api/hello`, just a simple starting route. However, I only get 401 responses every time. After trying that several times, I used the test code from Auth0 for the API, and got a token using `cURL`, and then making the request with that token (again using `cURL`, but I still get 401s.

It seems that I've done something incorrect and am not communicating properly between my Angular app and the Nest app. I am also clearly not reading the tutorial correctly. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
// jwt.strategy.ts
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from "passport-jwt";
import { passportJwtSecret } from "jwks-rsa";

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    console.log("constructor called");
    super({
      secretOrKeyProvider: passportJwtSecret({
        cache: true,
        rateLimit: true,
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 5,
        jwksUri: `${"https://my-domain.auth0.com/"}.well-known/jwks.json`,
      }),

      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      audience: "http://localhost:3333/",
      issuer: "https://my-domain.auth0.com/",
      algorithms: ["RS256"],
    });
  }

  validate(payload: unknown): unknown {
    console.log(payload);
    return payload;
  }
}
```

#### Of Note

The `console.log` from the constructor above is called when the app starts up. However, this `validate` method seems to never be called because the `console.log` is not hit.

```
// app.controller.ts
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
  @Get('hello')
  getData(): Message {
    return this.appService.getData();
  }
}
```

Also, when I go to the Logs section of Auth0, I don't see any failed transactions, so I don't think it's actually trying to validate the token.

Comment: If you;'re getting a 401, you're probably sending an invalid token. This can be due to an invalid config, or due to the token being expired. You can use [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to debug the token

Answer (score 2):

It took a little while to figure out the issue, and it turned out to be pretty simple.

First, it appears there was a potential issue with the browser caching some data, which was causing some issues. Second, I had a trailing slash on the `audience` value in my NestJS file. In Auth0's dashboard, the identifier was `http://localhost:3333`. In the TypeScript file, I had `http://localhost:3333/`. That mismatch caused the issue.

Another thing that contributed to solving the issue was that in the Angular app, we needed to provide the `audience` when initializing the authentication module as well.

With these minor changes, things seem to be working now.